# calculating the number of possible arrangements in chess

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In case you don't know, there are **64** squares on a chess board and 32 pieces (16 pawns, 4 rooks, 4 bishops, 4 knights, 2 queens and 2 kings) in a chess game. That means one square can take **33** different values counting the empty.

I want to calculate the number of all possible arrangements on a chess board logic or not.

I made this calculation:

$$64\cdot(33!/16!\cdot4!\cdot4!\cdot4!\cdot2!\cdot2!)$$

Is that true? If not, can you tell me the true calculation?

Comment: Also I notice that your $16!$ in the denominator fails to distinguish between black pawns and white pawns, so can't be right under any reasonable interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that one square can take 33 different values is only true if you can distinguish between the two white knights, and between the two white rooks, and among the 8 white pawns, and so on. With that assumption, the number of arrangements is $64\times63\times\cdots\times33$.